# Getting error - The policy assignment 'xyz' create request is invalid. Policy assignment scope must match the scope specified in the URI

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

I am trying to create an ARM template which creates a policy definition and an policy assignment as well. While creating policy assignment, I am getting an error that says - `"The policy assignment 'xyz' create request is invalid. Policy assignment scope  '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/providers/subscriptions/' must match the scope specified on the Uri  '/subscriptions/<subscription_id>'"` and the policy does not get assigned to the subscription level. Not sure the reason for this error. Pasting the part of the script here.

```
    {
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments",
  "apiVersion": "2021-06-01",
  "name": "require-tags",
  "properties":{
    "scope": "[subscriptionResourceId('/subscriptions' ,parameters('targetSubs'))]",
    "policyDefinitionId": "[extensionResourceId(variables('subscriptionScope'), 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions' ,  variables('policyDefinitionName'))]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[format('Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/{0}', variables('policyDefinitionName'))]"
  ]
}
```

and the variable is defined as follows -

```
  "variables": {
"subscriptionScope":"[subscriptionResourceId('/subscriptions' ,parameters('targetSubs'))]",
"policyDefinitionName": "RequireTagsifnotPresent"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to deploy to a different subscription scope.
If you're using "az deployment sub create" to deploy the ARM, make sure you set beforehand the subscription to the "targetSubs" that you use in your template (az account set targetSubs).